# Angularjs application crash 'Error: [injector:modulerr]'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular.JS, trying to learn debugging errors.

My application have 5 pages all are working fine except one page, while loading I am getting this error

```
Error:[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=newIntake...
```

I am getting one more error:

```
TypeError: Accessing the 'arguments' property of a function is not allowed in strict mode\n at Anonymous function.
```

while researching I learnt this error appear if any file is missing, i check all file loading in this particular page are available.

I really appreciate if someone provide me any hint or point me where to see exact error which could solve this issue.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Error clearly says that the `newIntake` module is not instantiated. Check if the module file is loaded, are there any syntax errors, spelling mistakes.

Comment: can you upload code in plukr?

Comment: Regarding the first error. You shouldn't truncate the error because it contains the information on the cause of the error. Actually, the error message is clickable in Chrome and leads to the page that explains the problem in readable form. Regarding the second error. It is caused by [deprecated property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments). Search for `.arguments` through code base. The question doesn't contain enough information to get a quality answer.

Comment: @estus, I am sorry to not provide enough Information.
Actually I was not clear myself where and what the issue is.

We are not suppose to use Chrome, client have IE so we develop in IE itself.

Comment: Is it a problem to open the app in Chrome? You can use the app wherever you wish, but Chrome is considered a de facto browser for web development. The described behaviour for Angular errors is actual for Chrome console, I'm not sure if IE can open the error in the same manner. Any way, you could at least post the entire error message. Please, don't truncate it, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The error because you are accessing `arguments` property of a `function` that is not allowed in strict mode. You have two options. First one, remove `use strict`, may be in the top  two lines of your code. Or you can go to second option that is access the arguments with a variable instead of accessing them directly. For example, you are calling somewhere like,

`ABC('hi');` and

Accessing like

`function ABC(name){`

```
              console.log(arguments);  // remove this as it is not allowed in strict mode

              console.log(name); // use this
```

`}`

Comment: This is not correct. The error refers to [`arguments` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments), not `arguments` object.